# Bluetooth Connectivity Android

Tags: java, android

i am posting complete code to understand it correctly..Code run fine but when i connect the new search devices by clicking on menu items then application crashes...
problem is in method:
    listViewPairedDevices.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
please help me

```
package com.example.bluetoothcheck5;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 0;
  private BluetoothSocket mmSocket=null;
  private InputStream mmInStream;
  private  OutputStream mmOutStream;
  private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-  0800200c9a66");
    private static final int REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE_BT = 0;
    protected ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;

     BluetoothDevice mDevice ;
    protected BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter =   BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mArrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,0);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
final TextView out=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.out);
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan);
final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
 final Button buttonSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
    final ListView listViewPairedDevices = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewneww);
listViewPairedDevices.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);


final Button buttonnewdev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonnew);
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

// Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);



 if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
   out.append("device not supported");
 }
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }
  });
  button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {

               Context context = getApplicationContext();
               CharSequence text = "MAKING YOUR DEVICE DISCOVERABLE";
               int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

               Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
               toast.show();
            Intent enableBtIntent = new   Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE_BT);

        }
    }
 });
 button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {  

        mBluetoothAdapter.disable();

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
           CharSequence text = "TURNING_OFF BLUETOOTH";

           Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
           toast.show();
    }


 });

buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        Set<BluetoothDevice> mPairedDevices =   mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if (mPairedDevices.size() > 0) 
        {
            for (   BluetoothDevice mDevice : mPairedDevices) 
            {
                Log.v("Title", "PairedDevices: " + mDevice.getName() + " " +  mDevice.getAddress());
                //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), mDevice.getName(),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), mDevice.getAddress(),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                mArrayAdapter.add(mDevice.getName());
                mArrayAdapter. notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }




        //Intent myIntent= new Intent(v.getContext(),Activity2.class);
         //startActivity(myIntent);
     }

});
buttonnewdev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {



       if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
           mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        // Request discover from BluetoothAdapter
       mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

    }

  });


   listViewPairedDevices.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
           mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        Toast.makeText(arg1.getContext(), "Clicked", T   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        ConnectThread(mDevice);

    }

  });


















 }
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device =   intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
            if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            setTitle(R.string.select_device);
            if (mArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                String noDevices =   getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                mArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
            }
        }
    }
 };

public void ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
    // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
    // because mmSocket is final
    BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
    mDevice = device;

    // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
    try {
        // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
        tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    } catch (IOException e) { }
    mmSocket = tmp;


    try {
        // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
        // until it succeeds or throws an exception
        mmSocket.connect();
    } catch (IOException connectException) {
        // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException closeException) { }
        return;
    }

      // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
     manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
  }

/** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket 
 * @return */


    public void manageConnectedSocket(BluetoothSocket socket) {

     mmSocket = socket;
     InputStream tmpIn = null;
     OutputStream tmpOut = null;

     // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
     // member streams are final
     try {
         tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
         tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
     } catch (IOException e) { }

     mmInStream = tmpIn;
     mmOutStream = tmpOut;
 }

 public void run() {
     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
     int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

     // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
     while (true) {
         try {
             // Read from the InputStream
             bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
             // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
          //   mHandler.obtainMessage("hhg", bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             break;
         }
     }
 }

 /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
 public void write(byte[] bytes) {
     try {
         mmOutStream.write(bytes);
     } catch (IOException e) { }
 }

 /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
 public void cancel() {
     try {
         mmSocket.close();
     } catch (IOException e) { }
 }



  }
```

Comment: Please post the logcat, and what line numer the issue is at. That's a huge wall of code and it's hard to get through and the formatting is non existant.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly an issue in the Toast here:

```
    listViewPairedDevices.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Toast.makeText(arg1.getContext(), "Clicked", T   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ConnectThread(mDevice);
        }
    });
}
```

Where you have ..."Clicked", T    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

It should be:

> Toast.makeText(arg1.getContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();